# Reduce Launch image time

Tags: ios

Please anyone suggest me to **reduce the time** that launch image occupies for splash screen.
I have a video(GIF) playing as splash screen. The slides are only 1 sec long; so in splash screen image it takes more time.

Comment: Hi, launch screen is visible till all the resources are not loaded also it wait for the execution of didFinishLaunching in AppDelegate.
So its totally depends on hardware for launch image loading time.